# Is there a difference between "Coinsurance" and "Coinsurance after deductible"?

Tags: terminology, health-insurance

I'm looking at plans on the coveredCA site, and I see both terms used. However, my understanding is that coinsurance only kicks in after the deductible has been paid anyways, so "coinsurance after deductible" seems redundant both in and of itself and with just the term "coinsurance."
[image: screencap from coveredCA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "coinsurance after deductible" seems redundant

You're right, it's redundant.

If a plan has a deductible, the deductible applies unless it is waived.  A deducible is the amount of money the insured pays before the carrier will pay. 
 The comparison you are looking at is simply reversing the waive logic.  Rather than indicating where the deductible is waived, it is indicating where the deductible applies.  You might notice that 3 of the 4 benefits listed are "after deductible" meaning the deductible has been waived for one of them.

"Coinsurance after deductible" is redundant because everything is after deductible unless the deductible is waived.

Comment: To the downvoter, when would a carrier pay coinsurance before a deductible was met?  The insured meets the deductible THEN The carrier begins paying that is the definition of a deductible, except for benefits where the deductible is waived.  This is redundant for clarity but it's still redundant.

Comment: I'm guessing the DVers are thinking that it's possible to have coinsurance before the deductible is met. I've never heard of that but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: @TTT I've never heard of that, I've never seen. It's directly opposed to the definition of a deductible.  Unless the deductible is specifically waived (like office visit co-pays or preventive care) it applies.  This is a simple answer to a simple question.

Comment: I just did a search for "coinsurance before deductible". There were plenty of hits, though they are mostly non reputable links. Except one and it says "0% coinsurance before deductible" which is specifically waived like you stated. Perhaps before ACA there actually were some specific types of coverage that had coinsurance before the deductible is met. I can't remember any though. Perhaps nowadays, in the US, coinsurance always implies "after deductible", which, if true, would be redundant. Good edit btw.

Comment: It's not redundant.  You will sometimes see things with coinsurance but no deductible.

Comment: @quid I've seen it in the past but I don't have any examples around.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, It's not about whether its a copay or coinsurance.  It's redundant because "after deductible" by the definition of the word deductible is the default on plans with a deductible.  Additionally, I've literally never seen a plan that has a deductible and waives it for a benefit paid on a coinsurance basis.

Comment: It seems nobody yet realizes that they can very well make you pay coinsurance _before_ the deductible is met: for example, first bill you pay 20% coinsurance, and 80% (which you also pay) counts against the deductible, etc. with 4k deductible, you'd pay the first _5k_, 20% of 5k = 1k is coinsurance, and the other 4k are deductible...

Comment: @Aganju, have you ever actually seen that happen?  That would indicate that your coinsurance responsibility/payments would not accrue toward the deductible.

Comment: I have given up understanding their bills years ago, but I doubt they are that absurd yet... I was pointing out that the wording is not redundant, but discriminates from another possibility.

Comment: @Aganju, You're just making up a very hypothetical situation.

Comment: As commented on the other answer: isn't the difference that out-of-network spending (i.e. “100% coinsurance” in the table) does not count towards your deductible?

Comment: @Relaxed, No, I read the table above to indicate that OON pharmacy benefits are not covered which is extremely common.  In fact, calling it coinsurance is disingenuous, because OON you owe your portion of the covered amount and all charges above that. 100% coinsurance could be construed to mean that the member paid portions (100% of the covered amount) would apply to the OON deductible/OOP max.  The ACA mandates that all member cost sharing for covered benefits will apply toward the OOP Max.  This person should look at a benefits summary made by the carrier not by covered CA.

Answer (score 4):

"Coinsurance" means the amount you have to pay on any claim.

When they say "20% coinsurance after deductible", this means that you have to pay the entire amount of all bills that this clause applies to until you reach the deductible, and after that you pay 20% and the insurance company pays 80%. "100% coinsurance" means that the deductible is irrelevant, you always pay 100%.

I suppose it's redundant in the sense that if they said "100% coinsurance after deductible", that would mean you pay 100% until you reach the deductible, and after that you pay ... 100%.

Comment: Nice example of what would have been redundant. Hehe.

Comment: Not sure it's redundant, isn't the difference that out-of-network spending does not count towards your deductible?

Comment: @Relaxed That's a good point.